# COBOL process FSPCCURR is failing in PT8.55.07 environment

Tags: cobol, peoplesoft

We are upgrading PeopleTools from PT8.54.06 to PT8.55.07, and during testing of the COBOL process FSPCCURR in the PT8.55 environment we are getting this error:

```
In Pgm Section  : SQLRT: DA000-FETCH With
    Return Code: 09980 Error Message   : SQLRT: Buffer for field too small for fetched data
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is this related to a piece of code you have written for the PeopleTools environment? If so, may we see that code?

Comment: Are you using a Unicode database?  If so I believe there is a program you need to run before compiling to convert the COBOLs to be Unicode compatible.  If I remember it doubles the size of the buffers inside the COBOL program